# how to get prototype properties list

Tags: javascript

As **Object.getOwnPropertyNames()** return an array of properties i would like to know
Is there any function in javascript that return a array of prototype.

```
function PersonInfo(){
    this.name=null;
    this.sex=null;
    this.age=null;
}

PersonInfo.prototype.getPersonInfo1=function(){

};

PersonInfo.prototype.getPersonInfo2=function(){

};

var pI=new PersonInfo();
//HERE we can use getOwnPropertyNames(pI) to get array of properties in PersonInfo() that result Array["name","sex","age"]
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(pI));
```

Similarly how to get

> Array["getPersonInfo1","getPersonInfo2"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` like this

```
Object.keys(PersonInfo.prototype)
```

Comment: This is generally sufficient, and is the most convenient method, but note that it only returns enumerable properties.

Answer (score 1):

In ES6 you can use [Object.getPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) function:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(pI)));
// Array [ "constructor", "getPersonInfo1", "getPersonInfo2" ]
```

Note: Currently it is not working in all environments (especially older browsers). You need to check if your environment supports it

Comment: >__proto__ deprecated in ES6

Comment: Thanks but it returns constructor also... I will manage it.... however anyother way that only returns Array["getPersonInfo1", "getPersonInfo2"]

Comment: you can filter out `constructor` item